# SQL Profiler duration vs SSMS duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-profiler

I have a stored procedure that is executing in roughly 15.5 seconds in SSMS.  When using: set statistics time on; I get the following results:

***SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 72018 ms,  elapsed time = 15465 ms.***

When I view the execution of the same stored procedure in sql profiler, my duration column displays 153688 micro seconds or roughly 153 seconds by the following calculation: 153688/1000

I also checked the datediff on StartTime and EndTime profiler columns and got the same value:

```
select DATEDIFF(s,'2014-01-17 17:24:45','2014-01-17 17:27:19')
--datediff in seconds = 154
```

So my questions are: 
What is sql profiler measuring that SSMS is not and where should I start to troubleshoot the problem?
Why is the stored procedure taking over 2 minutes to execute when my application calls it, but only 15.4 seconds when executed in SSMS.

Comment: Microsecond <> Millisecond

Comment: Last question: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Yes I know Micorsecond <> Millisecond.  SQL Profiler displays micro second while setting statistics time on will display milliseconds.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan - looks like I have some light reading for the weekend.